# How to merge 2 shapefiles in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, shapefile, java, merge

Using ArcObjects SDK for Java, I have the full path of 2 shapefiles: String in1, String in2, and I want to merge them using the geoprocessing tool [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geoprocessing/tools/datamanagementtools/Merge.html).

I tried to several methods:

```
IGpValueTableObject vtObject = new GpValueTableObject();
vtObject.setColumns(2);
vtObject.setValue(0, 0, in1);
vtObject.setValue(0, 1, 1);
vtObject.setValue(1, 0, in2);
vtObject.setValue(1, 1, 2);
```

or

```
IGpValueTableObject vtObject = new GpValueTableObject();
vtObject.setColumns(2);
vtObject.addRow("'" + in1 + "' 1");
vtObject.addRow("'" + in2 + "' 2");
```

or

```
IGpValueTableObject vtObject = new GpValueTableObject();
vtObject.setColumns(2);
vtObject.loadFromString(in1 + ";" + in2);
```

Before executing the the gp tool:

```
Merge merge = new Merge();
merge.setInputs(vtObject);
merge.setOutput(out);
IGeoProcessorResult result = gp.execute(merge, null);
```

In each case, I get this error: AutomationException: 0x80004005 - Unspecified error

I guess I am wrong in my way to set up the Merge inputs but I didn't find any samples explaining how to do it, except in C# or VB.

Comment: Not tested but I think you may be adding apostrophes when none is needed? So addRow would be vtObject.addRow(in1 + " 1").

Comment: Yes why not, I will test soon. I tested to put apostrophes like in the python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a very simple solution for this case:

```
Merge merge = new Merge(in1 + ";" + in2, out);
```

It works well. But I didn't find a way to feed the IGpValueTableObject.